# Pairwise differences between survreg survival curves (survival package) using emmeans

Tags: statistics, survival-analysis, survival, pairwise, emmeans

I'm using survreg from the 'survival' package to model survival curves. I'm interested in obtaining pairwise differences between levels of factors. I've tried using pairwise_survdiff from the 'survminer' package, but the function won't work with either interactions or with cluster() factors.

I've used emmeans a lot before with linear models, but I can't figure out how (or exactly what) emmeans is using to compare pairwise differences between curves.

Here's an example model:

```
library(survival) 
library(emmeans)

lung.model <- survreg(Surv(time, status) ~ factor(sex) + factor(ph.ecog), lung)
```

plot the same model using flexsurv:

```
require(flexsurv)
lung.model  <- flexsurvreg(s ~  factor(sex) + factor(ph.ecog),dist='weibull',data=lung)
plot(lung.model)
```

[image: survreg]

Use emmeans to obtain Tukey's pairwise differences:

```
emmeans(lung.model, pairwise ~ factor(sex)|factor(ph.ecog), adjust="tukey")
```

[image]

and the emmean for each factor level:

```
emmeans(lung.model,  ~factor(sex)|factor(ph.ecog))
```

[image]

How exactly are emmeans calculated for survreg objects? If this was a linear model I'd expect emmeans to report an average value for time on the X axis, but time isn't included as a factor in survreg objects. Is emmeans here reporting median survival times?

Also, how are the pairwise differences in the tukeys posthoc calculated?

EDIT

I'm still not following 100% here. With the following model:

```
library(survival) 
library(emmeans)
library(flexsurv)

#plot model
lung.model  <- flexsurvreg(Surv(time, status) ~  factor(ph.ecog),dist='weibull',data=lung)
plot(lung.model)

#emmeans
lung.model <- survreg(Surv(time, status) ~ factor(ph.ecog), lung)
emmeans(lung.model, pairwise ~ph.ecog, adjust="tukey", type = "response")
```

Is emmeans fitting a single linear function to the model (i.e. an overall fit for ph.ecog) and then working out significant differences for each different level from that overall model fit?

Is this why the response for each $emmeans corresponds to the same proportion of survival? Apologies for the basic question here, but I can't find anywhere else in the vignettes that explains how this is working for a survreg function!

Comment: They are estimates of mean log survival times. These are modeled as a linear function of the model parameters, and the estimates and contrasts are based on calculating the appropriate linear combinations of the regression coefficients. BTW, you don't need those factor() calls in the emmeans specs; just `~ sex | ph.ecog` will work fine.

Comment: Perfect @RussLenth, many thanks!

Comment: @RussLenth can I back-transform the mean log survival times to get the actual value? If so, how?

Comment: Use `type = "response"`. There are a number of vignettes and help files that I would suggest you take a look at.

Comment: @RussLenth I've spent a bit of time trying to understand this but it's still not clear. I've updated the above post with a clarification. If you have a moment to check if i'm following this correctly, it'd be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think you're expecting more detail than is available. emmeans() just estimates means, like it does for any model. With survreg(), you specify a probability model for the survival function, and emmeans() summarizes that model. If you want points along the survival curve, that's not something emmeans() does.